# WSO2 BAM REST API

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-bam

In BAM documentation it is stated that information which is not always available can be published as additional information in variable key-value pairs. An example is given about how to do this using data agent API. I want to do the same using REST api. Can some one explain how to send additional information via the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, It is not supported in REST API... This feature is only available for Tuple messages (Thrift transport) ... You can't send additional information via the REST API...

Answer (score 0):

Variable key-value pair facility is only available in Data Bridge level. (Java API level that is used by Data Agents) But it is not yet available in REST API level.

Answer (score 0):

Does it support in BAM2.3 now?
After reviewing the sample of restuful api, I found this is supported, like code below:

```
[
    {
        "payloadData" : ["IBM", 26.0, 848, 43.33, 2.3] ,
        "metaData" : ["123.233.0.1"] ,
        "correlationData" : ["2213-2324-2ffs-2444"],
        "timeStamp" : 1312345432
    }
    ,
    {
        "payloadData" : ["MSFT", 22.0, 233, 22.22, 4.3] ,
        "metaData" : ["5.211.1.1"],
        "correlationData" : ["1243-eeef-2969-3566"],
    }
]
```